# Send image/jpeg along with other form data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

After trying to investigate for a complete way on how to submit an image along with other form data to a REST API using AngularJS. The image is always intercepted on server as 'null', although it works perfectly when testing the REST API using [postman chrome](http://www.getpostman.com/) extension.

Here's the controller code below:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('image', $scope.fileName);
    formData.append('title', $scope.subject);
    formData.append('body', $scope.body);
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'formhandler',
        data    : formData,
        headers : {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
            return data;
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.openModal.hide();
    });
};
```

Thank you in advance, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like angular does not support file inputs in it's built in transformRequest. Look here for more Info: http://badwing.com/multipart-form-data-ajax-uploads-with-angularjs/

Comment: @mainguy thank you for your comment. However, the link you posted is for sending multipart to server. I would like to send Content-Type image/jpeg along with other form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long investigation, it appeared that the problem was in the file directive and not in the controller and by using the directive code below, I've been successfully able to post image file to server.

```
angular.module('yourApp').directive('file', [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<input type=\"file\" />",
        replace: true,
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
          var listener;
          listener = function() {
            return scope.$apply(function() {
              if (attr.multiple) {
                return ctrl.$setViewValue(element[0].files);
              } else {
                return ctrl.$setViewValue(element[0].files[0]);
              }
            });
          };
          return element.bind("change", listener);
        }
      };
    }
]);
```

For more information; check the following link:
https://gist.github.com/tdrozdowski/6468541

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to find a solution for that; I'm going to try to share it, then. Indeed, you are near the solution, I think. This is what I did:

On the controller:

```
var uploadImages = function () {
    var formData = new FormData(),
        len = $scope.Files.length, // Supposing that your images are here (the objects in the input type='file')
        i = 0;

    for ( ; i < len; i++) {
        formData.append('file[]', $scope.Files[i]);
        formData.append('title[]', $scope.FilesDetails[i].title); // If you need attach arrays of data
    }

    formData.append('moreInfo1', $scope.moreInfo1); // Adding other information
    formData.append('moreInfo2', $scope.moreInfo2);

    ImageManager.uploadImages(formData)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log('Success: ' + data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data + '. Status: ' + status);
        });
};
```

On the service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('ImageManager', function ($http) {
        uploadImages: function(formData) {
            return $http.post('uploadImages.php', formData, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            });
        }
    });
```

Then from PHP, in case is what you are using, you would need to check the $_FILES and $_REQUEST objects; the information is going to be there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you @DanielM for your answer. However, the above do not fix my problem which is sending an image with content-type image/jpeg along with other form data.

Comment: Oh, I see; and, just to ask, what do you want to do it so? In fact, what I can say is that doing it like I showed above you can consult (talking again about PHP, sorry if it's no your case) the file type through the $_FILES['input_name']['type'] property, and you are going to get what you would expect, for instance something like "image/jpeg".